# How to place an image to the right of a table in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to place an PNG to the right of a table, e.g.:

```
 _______    ___
|__|____|  |\ /|
|__|____|  | X |
|__|____|  |/_\|
Table      Image
```

The image cannot fill more than 50% of the screen width. The table expands to fill the remaining space.

- I tried using CSS columns, but the table data became strange.
- I tried putting the table inside another table, but this seems like poor code.

How can I place an image to the right of a table in CSS?

Answer (score 2):

You can float them:

```
table { float: left; width: 50% }
img { float: right; width: 50% }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ea27d/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block`

```
//css
table{
    display: inline-block;
}
img{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dz8A/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try making use of flexbox :)

(If you do view the example here in SO, please do so in full page)

```css
#main-div {
  display: flex;
}

#img-1 {
  max-width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 723px){
  #main-div {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="main-div">
  <table class="table" id="item-1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" id="img-1">
</div>
```

Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/wQzeNX) :)

On the other hand, you can limit the size of the image to 50% by setting its `max-width` property to 50%.

### Edit: I only realized this was an old question lol.